# Absolute / Relative Positioning

Tags: css, css-position

Is there a way to position the boat at the bottom of this site www.favoriteltddesign.com with positioning so that it is always just below the waves? I currently have it resting on the bottom of the body of the page which has a different margin-bottom for certain breakpoints.

Comment: No-one is going to look into your site. If you want to get some help with us then post your relevant code here in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
bottom: 0px;
right: 0px;
position: fixed;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Fixed is not a good idea because the footer is not fixed... so your boat will move with the screen, which isn't what he wants.

Comment: See how that works on his site...  It isn't just switching the position of the element.